# setLayoutManager NullPointException in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to receive a list with an array in RecyclerView and get error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager
(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)'on a null object reference
```

RecyclerView widget's

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I tried to declare LayoutManager to final, but it doesn't help.

Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private InfAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main_appbar);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    InfAdapter mAdapter = new InfAdapter(this, getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

}
```

Adapter code:

```
public class InfAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InfAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

  private final Context context;
    private  List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();


    public InfAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder  holder, int position) {

        Information current  = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.title);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconid);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);

        }
    }
}
```

What has possibly gone wrong?

Comment: can you post your layout code too....does your layout code have RecyclerView like this `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` else you might get error

Comment: @Ranjith yes, thats included

Comment: The LogCat output should provide you with the specific line of code where the null pointer exception is occurring or you can run this in the debugger and put a break point at the setLayoutManger line of code and see which object is null.

Comment: Provide your entire layout file. This looks like the layout you set for the activity does not contain the id used for the recycler view.

Comment: Is the `RecyclerView` in `layout/activity_main_appbar.xml`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As @StenSoft noted in comments the problem was in 
`setContentView (R.layout.activity_main_appbar);` because of wrong activity layout content, instead of 
`setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Damn this copy paste... -_-

Comment: @nimi0112 ikr! LOL

Answer (score 10):

In my case this error comes because I did not create `RecyclerView` in one of my activity .

check your activity layout or fragment layout.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar ,but in kotlin and inside the

```
RecyclerView.apply {}
```

code, in the line :

```
layoutManager = viewManager
```

eventually I found out it was because I inflated the wrong layout to the fragment, in the line:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
```

Answer (score -1):

seriously, for the record, check the recicler view id

Comment: idea given by https://stackoverflow.com/a/42751385/21396068

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34032216)